# During Curl post how to percent encoading post parameter

Tags: php, post, curl

I want to post my data in percent encoding format In Curl Php.
I am posting a data name="test test test";
I want that to be encoded as test%20test%20test but it is posting data as test+test+test.

before passing in curl also I made rawurlencode method to percent encoding but curl converted it to normal encoding.

Please let me  know what I am missing?

```
//creating my post parameter


 $params = array();  



 foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
$params[] = $key . '=' . rawurlencode($value);

  }

return implode('&', $params);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Have you tried `urlencode()` ?

Comment: yes I tried with rawurlencode . I need it in % encoading format

Comment: Try to change this `$params[] = $key . '=' . rawurlencode($value);` to `$params[] = $key . '=' .$value;` and replace `return implode('&', $params);` with `$data = urlencode(implode('&', $params));`

Comment: I tried with this but it is not working. I need to encode the values and keys only.

Answer (score 2):

POST data is supposed to be encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  In this encoding, spaces are represented as `+`, not %20 and the result you are getting (`test+test+test`) is correct. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1

This is why `curl` translated the `%20` to `+`.  The PHP cURL library only supports POSTing in  `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data` MIME types.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want it in %20 encoded format. Is there any way